# Class tx_snowbabel_system_indexing of the registered task could not be found.

Tags: php, typo3

**Class tx_snowbabel_system_indexing of the registered task could not be found. You should re-install the extension that provided it or simply delete this task.**

I've updated snowbabel extension. Now the scheduler shows this error. Any Idea?

Thanks In advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you've upgraded the extension. The most recent version uses namespaces.

Deleting the scheduler task and adding it again should solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've been testing now. One more thing I want to ensure is I have a lot of translations in the old version. As you told I updated the snowbabel extension, whether the old translations will be maintained or it override those values?.

Comment: The extension writes the translations in the locallang files of the corresponding extensions directly, so an upgrade of snowbabel shouldn't affect the translations. An update of the individual extension where you have amended translations will though.

Comment: But now I've a l10 folder in typo3conf directory.